# How to do a pull request on master of other's repo? (New branch was created)

Tags: git, github

I am trying to contribute to some library. In the contributing docs of that repository were written:

1)clone repository:

I did it `git clone URL here`
 1.

2)Create a branch

Done `git checkout -b ...`

Then made edits inside files. After this it says these 2 steps:

3)Commit the file to the repo

4) Create a pull request on master
In the pull request title, put the title of your changed file - 
and Submit the pull request

So what should I do dor 3rd and 4th steps? Which commands to type to complete the contribution in this case?

Answer (score 1):

After creating branch, Perform the following commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m "write your comment here"
git push origin your-branch-name   // which you just created using checkout command
```

After this you can go to your git repository and raise the Pull Request on master by following these setps:

1. Go to your git repository in browser.
2. Click on `New Pull Request` button.
3. Enter some text in `title` textbox.
4. Click on `Create Pull Request` button.

Now you have raised the Pull Request and your work is done. Now the other member who has access to merge the PR, will come and `Approve your changes` and then `Merge the pull request`.